# How to force my system to use the nvidia GPU with nouveau instead of the intel GPU?

Tags: nvidia, displaylink

I have a laptop with an Nvidia GTX 1650 and an intel UHD Graphics 630. I have not installed the closed source drivers for the nvidia card because they are not compatible with displaylink (sidenote: they do "work", but it is not supported by the driver and the CPU consumption and operating temperature of the laptop is ridiculously high). For the same reason I can not use my intel graphics.
After starting my laptop today, while it was plugged into the displaylink dock, it would not boot into a working desktop environment.
After booting without the dock, I see that it is using the intel GPU, while it used the Nvidia with the niveau driver, until yesterday.
How can I switch to the nvidia GPU, without using the proprietary driver?

I am on **Kubuntu 21.04** (This means I am on xorg and not wayland)

```
Linux PROX15 5.11.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 20:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What commands and corresponding output are you having to determine which GPU the PC is using?

Comment: i just opened the KDE system settings, it is diplayed under graphics. When I unistal the proprietary drivers it shows intel.....

Comment: Did you check the /etc/modprobe.d directory for anything blacklisting noveau?  Might be a leftover depending upon how the proprietary drivers were installed/uninstalled,  Remove such line if any found.  You might need nomodeset on the kernel boot line with the nouveau drivers (black screen at login etc.).

Comment: @ubfan1 good idea, but `sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep nouveau` returns an empty string.